# Updating views outside a Recycler view on change of recycler view item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm new to android and is working on an online shopping project. For this the Cart fragment uses a Recycler View. And on removal or updating of item, the Total amount and the number of items of the cart should change.
Given below is the layout of the cart fragment.

[image]

What I have in mind is to refresh(load) the fragment again on recycler view item removal or updation. Is there any other option to perform this action with a better solution. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Update RecyclerView `adapter` with latest data available after deletion/updatation & call `notifyDataSetChanged` method of `adapter` to reflect the changes.

Comment: @NatarajKR, the suggestion you have given is to update the recycler view yeah. But I need to know how order total and the no. of items(that does not belong to the recycler view items) can be changed, on updating of recycler view items.

Comment: Order total and no. of items can be changed in two ways. One way is to access the textViews using their id's and changing the text after calculating total amount and no. of items. The other way is using dataBinding and liveData.  Refer this documentation: (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way)

Comment: @NatarajKR, thanks for the tip. Will consider that.